# Smooth dependence of diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I guess the following question refers to a standard result, but I cannot find a good reference or figure out the details.

Suppose $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and positive definite and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is self-adjoint with respect to $S$, i.e. $A^T S = S A$. Then it follows from basic linear algebra that there exists a decomposition
$$ A = U^T D U$$
where $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix and $U \in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $S$-orthogonal, i.e. $U^T S U = I$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

I wonder now if the matrices $(U,D)$ depend smoothly on $S$ and $A$? To make this more precise, replace $S$ by a smooth family $S_t$ of positive definite matrices and let $A_t$ be a smooth family satisfying $A_t^T S_t = S_t A_t$. As above there exists for every fixed $t$ a decomposition
$$A_t = U_t^T D_t U^T_t$$
with a diagonal matrix $D_t$ and a $S_t$-orthogonal matrix $U_t$. But is it possible to choose $U_t$ and $D_t$ to depend **smooth** on $t$?

I think it should be possible to solve this problem by the implicit function theorem, but I cannot figure out the details..

Comment: The answer is *yes* in the case where $D_t$ has no repeated eigenvalues, and *no* in the case where $D_t$ does.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60533/can-always-a-family-of-symmetric-real-matrices-depending-smoothly-on-a-real-param